# TypeScript Theme Switch types erros

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I had a useHooks to do thema exchange using localStorage, but I started using typescript and I had difficulty typing my code

my theme type:

```
type colors = {
  primary: string;
  secondary: string;
  background: string;
  text: string;
};
export type ITheme = {
  type: string;
  colors: colors;
};

export const lightTheme: ITheme = {
  type: 'light',
  colors: {
    primary: '#fff',
    secondary: '#2a2d34',
    background: '#FFF',
    text: '#333',
  },
};

export const darkTheme: ITheme = {
  type: 'dark',
  colors: {
    primary: '#fff',
    secondary: '#2a2d34',
    background: '#FFF',
    text: '#333',
  },
};
```

my custom hook:

```
import { darkTheme, lightTheme, ITheme } from '../themes/index';

type getInitialTheme = () => ITheme;

export default function useAppTheme(defaultTheme: ITheme = lightTheme) {
  const [theme, _setTheme] = useState(getInitialTheme);

  function getInitialTheme(): getInitialTheme {
    const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

    if (
      JSON.parse(savedTheme) === 'dark' ||
      JSON.parse(savedTheme) === 'light'
    ) {
      return JSON.parse(savedTheme) === 'dark' ? darkTheme : defaultTheme;
    } else {
      return defaultTheme;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(theme.type));
  }, [theme]);

  return {
    theme,
    setTheme: ({ setTheme, ...theme }) => {
      if (theme.type === 'dark') {
        return _setTheme(darkTheme);
      } else {
        return _setTheme(lightTheme);
      }
    },
  };
}
```

But I am getting errors in the following functions:

> getInitialTheme()
>
> setTheme

on my getInitialTheme i got this:

[image]

[image]

and on my setTheme:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `getInitialTheme` should return an `ITheme`

```
function getInitialTheme(): ITheme
```

Null check should be done before.

```
if (
      savedTheme && 
      (JSON.parse(savedTheme) === 'dark' || JSON.parse(savedTheme) === 'light'))
```

Comment: Hello is there a need for me to typer my return from that useHook?
like this:

return {
    theme,
    setTheme: ({setTheme, ... theme}) => {
      if (theme.type === 'dark') {
        return _setTheme (darkTheme);
      } else {
        return _setTheme (lightTheme);
      }
    },
  };

can you help me with this?

Comment: It's not a return, setTheme is a function which takes arguments which are destructured.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it’s line type getInitialTheme = () => ITheme;

It’s redundant and not necessary, change the method getInitalTheme return type to ITheme